# Is it ok to call professors for LOR?

Tags: etiquette

I'm a student who has completed a Masters in physics and taking a gap year. I currently need to receive letters of recommendations from professors of the institution I got my masters from. But because I already left school, I cannot visit them in person. Would it be inappropriate to call professors via phone if they don't reply to my LOR requests?

Edit: I have already sent email requests reminding them of who I am and what class I took from them. But I did not hear back and was wondering if I giving a call would be inappropriate.

Comment: "Would it be inappropriate to call professors via phone if they don't reply to my LOR requests?" as in "I got in touch with them by email"?  If so, add this information (Because then, the professor in question already has an address to get back in touch to you, too.  Because this email may recapitulate briefly your profile like *I attended you advanced class of basket weaving 305 in 2020/21, was in the top x% of the final exam, got awarded "best poster at conference x" for presenting results of the lab class, co-authored paper x which was submitted for journal y / got accepted, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Just give it a try if you have the phone number, your request is reasonable. Standard communication conventions apply.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would you say it would be better to contact a postdoc of the professor first?

Comment: @VVC, that depends heavily on various factors unknown to us, such as your relationship with the professors, their personalities, their current workload, their current mood... but if you have their number (either directly from them or from a publicly available source), they should have a way to deal with you calling directly.

Comment: @VVC Situations may vary, but it doesn't seem right to me to treat a postdoc like an administrative assistant. A postdoc's job is research, not answering the phone for their boss.